# Digital ocean droplet getting full in memory and Nextjs build is getting killed

Tags: node.js, next.js, digital-ocean

I have a droplet with 8gb ram. I am running 3 projects. Two in nextjs and 1 nodejs framework. For all the projects we run npm run build and nextjs takes lots of memory to build. Now it seems server 5.4GB always in use and only 5/6 users are testing the projects.

pm2 screenshot

https://ibb.co/pxbhqBT

htop screenshots

https://ibb.co/NtbXHq8

https://ibb.co/z5ffD2r

Any idea what could go wrong?
Thank you.